# mysql inserting data into multiple tables

Tags: mysql, reference, insert

My tables are students, class, and studentclasses. They have many to many relationships among them. Can anyone tell me why the following code is not working?

```
START TRANSACTION;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

INSERT INTO 'students'('StudentID','Fname','Lname')
VALUES (Null,'name','lastname')
# 1 row affected.

SET @student = LAST_INSERT_ID();
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

INSERT INTO `classes`(`classID`, `className`)
VALUES (Null, 'Maths');# 1 row affected.

SET @class = LAST_INSERT_ID();
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

INSERT INTO `studentclasses`(`classID`, `studentID`)
VALUES (@class, @student);
# 1 row affected.

COMMIT;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: as you can see, Last_insert_identity is returning 0 rows. so my studentclasses table remains empty. i.e no values are entered into it

Comment: Firstly - fix syntax errors: 'INSERT INTO 'students'('StudentID','Fname','Lname') VALUES (Null,'name','lastname')' -> 'INSERT INTO students(StudentID, Fname, Lname) VALUES(Null,'name','lastname');'

Comment: @Devart fixed, still doesn't work. same comments are given back by mySQL.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Have you tried running `SELECT * FROM studentclasses` after `COMMIT` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO students(StudentID,Fname,Lname) VALUES (Null,'name','lastname');
SET @student = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO classes(classID, className) VALUES (Null, 'Maths');
SET @class = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO studentclasses(classID, studentID) VALUES(@class, @student);

COMMIT;
```

---

It should work, try this example on new database -

```
CREATE TABLE classes(
  classID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  className VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (classID)
);

CREATE TABLE studentclasses(
  classID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  studentID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE students(
  StudentID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Fname VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  Lname VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO students(StudentID,Fname,Lname) VALUES (Null,'name','lastname');
SET @student = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO classes(classID, className) VALUES (Null, 'Maths');
SET @class = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO studentclasses(classID, studentID) VALUES(@class, @student);

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM students;
+-----------+-------+----------+
| StudentID | Fname | Lname    |
+-----------+-------+----------+
|         1 | name  | lastname |
+-----------+-------+----------+

SELECT * FROM classes;
+---------+-----------+
| classID | className |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Maths     |
+---------+-----------+

SELECT * FROM studentclasses;
+---------+-----------+
| classID | studentID |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         1 |
+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: @shani I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

use Insert statements in try block and catch the exception. if exception occur then do rollback